# I can't manage categories and products on magento

Tags: magento

I have problems about Magento.
I can't manage products or category. this just happen I don't know why.
when I click on manage categories it's not working as you can see this image

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbikd3pfd3b116c/mj1.jpg?dl=0

any solution to resolve?

Comment: compile once from admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm. What locale are you using? (See drop-down in bottom-left of the screenshot). I wonder if this is a double-byte character issue. I think maybe some JSON has been sent to the page but it has become corrupted possibly due to a double-byte character or some illegal or unescaped character in the JSON string.

If this just happened and you don't know why then:

a) Try some different locales from the drop down. If that doesn't help then:

b) Ensure all caches are cleared and refresh the page. If there is no change then:

c) I suggest you go to your last back up and recreate your website from that.

As mentioned it looks like the HTML of the page is all mixed up due to a malformed JSON string.

You could look at the returned content from the ajax call (using browser tools to study the response). That might give you a clue as to which part of the JSON string is corrupted. Maybe some part of the category attributes contains HTML tags which it shouldn't or there is a double-byte character or unescaped quotes in the JSON string - but that is just a guess. You might have to change your database settings and/or character settings to handle UTF16 characters.

Do all categories behave like that or just some of them? If it is only some of them then you might try deleting those categories and recreating them from scratch.

For the record I have never seen anything like this before.

Answer (score 0):

solution a and b not working, then I re-install and restore sql database by phpmyadmin everything almost complete like before only when I go to  Manage Categories then it's error.

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 682632812035